# Select the result of subquery when the outer query results null

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Im using `postgres 9.4`. I have two tables `tblcomponent` and `tblprofile` with no foreign key reference.

I want to select the data from both the tables. The relationship goes like

`tblcomponent` -> `tblprofile`

If the required data is not found in `tblprofile`, then only `tblcomponent` data must be selected. If the `tblcomponent` itself does not contain the requested data, then data need not be fetched.

Query:

```
SELECT subquery1.pk_szid, subquery1.xmldata, tblprofile.pk_szid, tblprofile.xmldata
FROM tblprofile,
 (SELECT tblcomponent.pk_szid, tblcomponent.xmldata 
  FROM tblcomponent WHERE pk_szid != 'DEFAULT' ) subquery1
WHERE  
CAST((xpath('/Profile/ComponentIDs/ComponentID[@Family="Flow"]/text()', tblprofile.xmldata))[1] AS TEXT) = subquery1.pk_szid
```

The above query returns if the data exists in both the table. How to get the data from `subquery1` when the outer query, i.e., where clause fails?

For example:

`tblcomponent`:

```
| pk_szid | xmldata        |
+---------+----------------+
| a1      |  xmldata       |
| a2      |  xmldata       |
| a3      |  xmldata       |
```

`tblprofile`:

```
| pk_szid | xmldata        |
+---------+----------------+
| b1      |  xmldata       | // contains a1
| b2      |  xmldata       | // does not contain any of tblcomponent.pk_szid
```

Here, 'b1' record's xmldata contains tblcomponent.pk_szid. When I give 'a1', the result for above query will be,

```
| pk_szid      | xmldata     |   pk_szid    |  xmldata     |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| a1           | xmldata     |     b1       |   xmldata    |
```

When I give 'a2',

```
  | pk_szid      | xmldata     |   pk_szid    |  xmldata     |
  +--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want something like,

```
 | pk_szid      | xmldata     |   pk_szid    |  xmldata     |
 +--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
 | a2           | xmldata     |              |              |
```

How to fetch this from `subquery1`?

Comment: Some sample data would be nice ^ ^

Comment: why don't you use left join like: `subquery1 left join tblprofile`?

Comment: The general description sounds like you want something along the lines of `SELECT ... FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1)`. But I cannot figure out what exactly that could be from that query attempt.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Find my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your outer and subquery into separate CTEs, then left join them:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT pk_szid, xmldata,
        CAST((xpath('/Profile/ComponentIDs/ComponentID[@Family="Flow"]/text()', xmldata))[1] AS TEXT) AS xml_content
    FROM tblprofile
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT pk_szid, xmldata 
    FROM tblcomponent
    WHERE pk_szid != 'DEFAULT'
)

SELECT
    t2.pk_szid,
    t2.xmldata,
    t1.pk_szid,
    t1.xmldata
FROM cte1 t1
LEFT JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.xml_content = t2.pk_szid;
```

There are a few variants of the above which we could write, but the basic idea is to compute the XPath value in a select clause, and then left join using that value.  A left join prevents the possibility of dropping records.

Comment: LEFT JOIN results in duplicate records. Since, the data is xml blob, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: I don't really know.  Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`?  With regard to which columns are duplicates appearing?

Comment: Can you alter your XPath expression to return only distinct values?  That might be the next thing I would try.  I am not an XPath expert, so I can't offer much help there.